# difference between Html.HiddenFor & HiddenInput attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, html.hiddenfor

**HiddenFor** description is:
Returns an HTML hidden input element for each property in the object that is represented by the specified expression.

I read that it is useful for fields in your Model/ViewModel that you need to persist on the page and have passed back when another call is made but shouldn't be seen by the user.

**HiddenInput** description is:
Represents an attribute that is used to indicate whether a property or field value should be rendered as a hidden input element.

Can you please tell me when is HiddenInput useful? and when to use it instead of Html.HiddenFor?

Thanks!

Comment: Out of interest, what is the source of your descriptions for these extension methods?

Answer (score 12):

`HiddenFor` is determined by the view - the view creates a Hidden input value from any element of the viewmodel or data.

`HiddenInput` is an attribute on a field in the (view)model - which means that it can be used across multiple views and indicates that this field should be hidden wherever it is rendered by an `EditorFor` helper